# What infrastructure still needs to be built for Monero that Bitcoin already has?

Tags: cryptocurrency-comparison

Things like services and various other infrastructure that Monero will need before it goes mainstream?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- SPV / Light clients with high level of trustlessness.
- Fiat <-> xmr gateways. (sort of encompasses all of the below)
- ATM machines.
- Billpay-type services
- Bitwage type services
- Payment processors (so amazon can accept Monero)
- Merchant infrastructure (so my local coffee shop can accept monero, kind of similar to payment processors).